# Python Inserting file into a file between two points has occasional errors

Tags: python

So I am trying to write a python script that will read in a file and replace the text between two lines. I have written the following script that does this. However on occasion it has a bug. I have confirmed that the lines delegating start and end of the block to replace are not changed by user error on these failed runs.

So the goal is to take a file that somewhere inside it has this

```
//#$$!VERILOGINSERT <START> DO NOT TOUCH*
Garbage stuff here
//#$$!VERILOGINSERT <END> DO NOT TOUCH
  assign led = 1'b1;

endmodule
```

Into this

```
//#$$!VERILOGINSERT <START> DO NOT TOUCH*
Cool code we generated in python
//#$$!VERILOGINSERT <END> DO NOT TOUCH
  assign led = 1'b1;

endmodule
```

I am using the following script to do it

```
verilogSource = "cpu/cpu.v"
pythonSource = "debug_console.py"
# IT IS IMPORTANT THAT START ENDS IN * and that is the only one
verilogInsertStart = "//#$$!VERILOGINSERT <START> DO NOT TOUCH*"
verilogInsertEnd = "//#$$!VERILOGINSERT <END> DO NOT TOUCH"

verilogSRC = open(verilogSource, "r+")
verilogSRC_STR = verilogSRC.read()
verilogSRC_SP = verilogSRC_STR.find(verilogInsertStart)
verilogSRC_EP = verilogSRC_STR.find(verilogInsertEnd)
assert(verilogSRC_SP >= 0)
assert(verilogSRC_EP >= 0)
verilogSRC_IP = verilogSRC_STR.find("*", verilogSRC_SP)
assert(verilogSRC_IP >= 0)
verilogSRC_MODSTR = verilogSRC_STR[:verilogSRC_IP] + "*\n" +  buildVerilog + "\n" + verilogSRC_STR[verilogSRC_EP:]
verilogSRC.seek(0)
verilogSRC.write(verilogSRC_MODSTR)
verilogSRC.close()
```

Again this usually works just find but on occasion it messes up and adds something to the end of the file.

Which causes a file like this

```
//#$$!VERILOGINSERT <START> DO NOT TOUCH*
please replace me
//#$$!VERILOGINSERT <END> DO NOT TOUCH
  assign led = 1'b1;

endmodule
```

To turn into this

```
//#$$!VERILOGINSERT <START> DO NOT TOUCH*
This is a great replacement 
//#$$!VERILOGINSERT <END> DO NOT TOUCH
  assign led = 1'b1;

endmodule_constant, write_data[2:0]};
//#$$!VERILOGINSERT <END> DO NOT TOUCH
  assign led = 1'b1;

endmodule
```

You can see the copied verilog end string in twice and overall added some code that was not supposed to be there.

It is worth noting I run a similar script for a different (python) file with the replacement being at just about the top of the file. When it bugs out on that file there ends up being no modifications other than sometimes a fragment of the last line repeated at the end of the file.

Any theories why this may be happening?

Comment: I don't think it's adding to the file, I think you are just not overwriting all the existing content. Try `verilogSRC.truncate()` after you seek.

Comment: This causes ```ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.```

Comment: After the seek, before the write and the close